# Closing dialog if post request is sucessful

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I am using React, Redux, NodeJS, and ExpressJS. I am also using material-ui for the front-end. I have created a dialog where users can input information and signup. Once a user clicks submit, a post req is made. Any errors that are returned would be than put into the errors object in the state. If any errors are returned (ex. passwords don't match) they are stated below the input field. If the submit button is clicked and there are no errors, the dialog stays open. How would I make the dialog be closed if there are no errors returned (the state.open should be turned to false). How would I do this. Here is my code:

authActions.js:

```
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/signup/done"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

signup.js:

```
class SignUpD extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password2: "",
      errors: {}
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAutenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false, errors: {} });
  };

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newUser = {
      username: this.state.username,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2
    };

    this.props.registerUser(newUser, this.props.history);
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <ListItem
          button
          style={{ paddingTop: 60, top: 0 }}
          onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Sign Up" />
        </ListItem>
        <Dialog
          fullWidth
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
          style={{ width: "100" }}
        >
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Register</DialogTitle>

          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              Enter registration details here
            </DialogContentText>
            <TextField
              margin="dense"
              name="email"
              label="Email Address"
              value={this.state.email}
              fullWidth
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            {errors.email && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.email}</div>}
            <TextField
              margin="dense"
              name="username"
              label="Username"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.username}
              fullWidth
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            {errors.username && (
              <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.username}</div>
            )}
            <TextField
              margin="dense"
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              fullWidth
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            {errors.password && (
              <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.password}</div>
            )}
            <TextField
              margin="dense"
              name="password2"
              label="Enter Password Again"
              value={this.state.password2}
              type="password"
              fullWidth
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            {errors.password2 && (
              <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.password2}</div>
            )}
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.onSubmit} color="primary">
              Register
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SignUpD.propTypes = {
  registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { registerUser }
)(withRouter(SignUpD));
```

If you need any clarification, or have questions let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using local state of the component to determine if dialog should be open, use the `redux store`. That way you can call an action to update the store from anywhere, and thus control if the dialog is open.

The same way you define `registerUser` in mapDispatch to props, you can define another action that dispatches something like `{type:'OPEN_DIALOG'}`, then in your reducer, you can respond to `OPEN_DIALOG` event by setting `state.dialogIsOpen` to true. Then in your `mapStateToProps`, make sure you're including `dialogIsOpen` from the redux state. And change anywhere that's using `this.state.dialogIsOpen` to be `this.props.dialogIsOpen`

Comment: Now I seem to be having the issue that the errors text is still there when I reopen the dialog. Do you know how I would get this text to go away once the dialog is reopened?